# Como passar dados através de uma Intent para a Main Activity?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Estou desenvolvendo um pequeno aplicativo android para exercitar o que já aprendi. O aplicativo consiste em duas Activity's, a MainActivity e uma segunda Activity. Na Main tenho um textView e um botão, enquanto que na segunda Activity tenho um editText e dois botões, para confirmação e cancelamento. O funcionamento do aplicativo deve ocorrer da seguinte maneira: ao pressionar o botão na Main Activity uma intent nos leva até a segunda Activity, e devemos digitar algum texto no editText e apertar o botão de confirmar, indo novamente para a MainActivity, onde o textView terá o valor digitado anteriormente.

O problema é que não sei como passar os dados digitados para a Main. Acredito que seja algo simples mas não tenho muitas ideias de como procurar. Gostaria de ao menos um norte para me guiar.

Obrigado desde já.

Comment: Acabei achando a resolução aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14292398/how-to-pass-data-from-2nd-activity-to-1st-activity-when-pressed-back-android utilizando o startActivityForResult

Answer (score 1):

Isso é bem simples. Pelo que entendi voce ja tem a logica do programa e só quer passar informações de uma Activity pra outra, então siga os passos.

Na **Activity** que tem o botão + texto, etc. Coloque isso no **onClick** do seu **Button**:

**Crie um novo Intent:**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityAtual.this, SegundaActivity.class);
```

> Onde esta segundaActivity.class vc preenche com o nome da Activity pra qual o botao vai redirecionar.

//Para mandar informações pra outra Activity

```
intent.putExtra("nomeConteudo", "Conteudo de texto que queira enviar");
```

//Redirecionar para outra activity

```
startActivity(intent);
```

Para receber as informações da Activity Anterior:

```
String valorRecebido;
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if(extras != null) {
 valorRecebido = extras.getString("nomeConteudo");
}
```

//Caso queira inserir em um TextView

```
textview.setText(valorRecebido);
```

Comment: Eu testei dessa forma no entanto sempre recebia um erro de NullPointer. Acredito que isso acontecia porque da primeira vez que executava a Activity Main nenhuma intent era passada para ela. Pra resolver esse problema é preciso utilizar, na Activity Main o método startActivityForResult.